# How to send data for more than one Ck Editors using Selenium Web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on the web application which is having five CK Editors.
    I know how to send data for one CK Editor and it is working fine but for multiple editors i'm facing problem as there is common class to identify. Can somebody please help me?

This is what i've tried -

```
       sectionLinks(driver, linkHiringWelcoming).click();
        if (driver.findElements(btnEdit).size() != 0)
            ClickEdit(driver, btnEdit).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(editor1));
        driver.findElement(body);
        WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        editable.clear();
        editable.sendKeys(" Hello");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(editor2));
        driver.findElement(body);
        WebElement editable1 = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        editable1.clear();
        editable1.sendKeys("Hello world”).
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        ClickSubmit(driver, btnSubmit).click();
```

and this is source code for Editors which is common for all :

```
 <iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeWelcome1435917971" aria-describedby="cke_63" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
                <head>
                <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
                </html>
             </iframe>
```

> following is the code with details :

```
    <div id="cke_ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116" class="cke_2 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116 cke_ltr cke_browser_gecko" lang="en" aria-labelledby="cke_ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116_arialbl" role="application" dir="ltr">
<span id="cke_ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Rich Text Editor, ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116</span>
<div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation">
<span id="cke_2_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" style="height: auto; -moz-user-select: none;" role="presentation">
<div id="cke_2_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;">
<span id="cke_117" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, ca2_HIRING_NewEmployeeHiring1436250116" aria-describedby="cke_117" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post some more html element around the ckeeditor

Comment: Hi madhan, please find the detailed code above.